# External documentation for PHP, no DocBook

Tags: php, phpdoc, docbook, restructuredtext, python-sphinx

I need a documentation system for a PHP project and I wanted it to be able to integrate external documentation (use cases, project scope etc.) with the documentation generated from code comments. It seems that phpDocumentor has exactly the right feature set, but external documentation must be written in DocBook which is too complex for our team.

If it were in python, sphinx would be just about perfect for this job (ReST is definitely simpler than docbook). Is there any way I can integrate external ReST documentation with the docs extracted from phpdoc? Should I just separate the external documentation (eg. use ReST for external and phpdoc for internal)? Or do you have a better suggestion for managing the external documentation?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756145/sphinx-for-php-code-documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert ReST to DocBook using pandoc.

Answer (score 0):

convert wordpress posts in DocBook style. here is the sample.

http://hashfold.com/techfold/wordpress-how-to-generate-docbook-style-posts/