# ReST strikethrough

Tags: restructuredtext, strikethrough, docutils

Is it possible to strike text through in Restructured Text?

Something that for example renders as a `<strike>` tag when converted to HTML, like: 
<strike>ReSTructuredText</strike>

Comment: When you use Sphinx, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24932178/2923406

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I checked the docs better, as suggested by Ville Säävuori, and I decided to add the strikethrough like this:

```
.. role:: strike
    :class: strike
```

In the document, this can be applied as follows:

```
:strike:`This text is crossed out`
```

Then in my `css` file I have an entry:

```
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to repeat this definition in each reST file that you want to use strike-throughs in, and it doesn't produce meaningful markup on the HTML side (it would be much better to produce a `<del>` or `<s>` tag).  I've posted the code for that below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493316/695591)

Comment: Since Docutils 0.17, the HTML5-writer uses <del> if a matching class value is found in inline, literal, or container elements, so defining `.. role:: del` suffices. Spinx users may consider to add the role definition to the [rst_prolog](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog).

Answer (score 18):

There is at least three ways of doing it:

```
.. role:: strike

An example of :strike:`strike through text`.

.. container:: strike

   Here the full block of test is striked through.

An undecorated paragraph.

.. class:: strike

This paragraph too is is striked through.

.. admonition:: cancelled
   :class: strike

I strike through cancelled text.
```

After applying `rst2html` you get:

```
<p>An example of <span class="strike">strike through text</span>.</p>
<div class="strike container">
Here the full block of test is striked through.</div>
<p>An undecorated paragraph.</p>
<p class="strike">This paragraph too is is striked through.</p>
<div class="strike admonition">
<p class="first admonition-title">cancelled</p>
<p class="last">I strike through cancelled text.</p>
```

You use them with a style

```
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Here I have taken the `admonition` directive as example but any
directive that allow the `:class:` option would do.

As it generates a `span` the `role` directive is the only one that
allow to apply your style to a part of a paragraph.

It is redundant to add a class `strike` to a directive also named
`strike`, as suggest Gozzilli, because the directive name is the default
class for the html output.

I have checked these syntax both with `rest2html` and **Sphinx**. But
while everything works as expected with  `rest2html` the `class`
directive fail with **Sphinx**. You have to replace it with

```
.. rst-class:: strike

This paragraph too is is striked through.
```

This is *only* stated in a small
[footnote of Sphinx reSt Primer](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#id3).

Comment: You sure about that link. I doesn't look like it goes where you intended.

Comment: @Tshepang, I checked, the link end up on a footnote that state: _When the default domain contains a class directive, this directive will be shadowed. Therefore, Sphinx re-exports it as rst-class._

Comment: Since Docutils 0.17, the HTML5-writer uses <del> if a matching class value is found in inline, literal, or container elements

Answer (score 16):

[According to the official spec](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html) there is **no directive for strikethrough** markup in ReST.

However, if the environment allows for :raw: role or you are able to write your own roles, then you can write a custom plugin for it.

Comment: I posted the plugin code below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493316/695591)

Answer (score 5):

I found the other answers very helpful. 
I am not very familiar with Sphinx but I am using it for a project. I too wanted the strike-through ability and have got it working based on the previous answers. 
To be clear, I added my strikethrough role as gozzilli mentioned but I saved it inside my conf.py using the rst_prolog variable as discussed in the stack overflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698702/custom-css-styles-in-sphinx). This means that this role is available to all of your rest files.

I then extended the base html template as described above by creating `layout.html`within `_templates`inside my source directory. The contents of this file are:

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% set css_files = css_files + ["_static/myStyle.css"] %}
```

This basically includes a custom css file to all your built default html docs.

Finally, in my _static directory within my source directory I included the file `myStyle.css` which contains:

```
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Which the other answers have already provided.

I am merely writing this answer as it wasn't obvious to me with my limited Sphinx experience which files to edit.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the user may have a different background, so here is no one solution that can be suitable for everyone.

## 1.Only one file

If you only use it only on one file. For example, you published a simple project to PyPI, and you may probably just only one README.rst file. The following may you want.

```
.. |ss| raw:: html

    <strike>

.. |se| raw:: html

    </strike>

single line
=============

|ss| abc\ |se|\defg

multiple line
=============

|ss|  
line 1

line 2
|se|

789
```

---

you can copy and paste it on this website: https://livesphinx.herokuapp.com/

and will see the picture as the following:

[image]

It's simple, and you can on directly see the preview on some IDE, for example, PyCharm.

---

**bellow is writing for the users of Sphinx**

## 2.beginner of Sphinx

If you are a beginner of Sphinx. ( I mean maybe you want to use Sphinx to create a document, but Python is not familiar for you ) then try as following:

```py
# conf.py

from pathlib import Path
html_static_path = ['_static', ]
html_css_files = ['css/user.define.css']  # If you want to control which HTML should contain it, you can put it on the HTML, which is very like the answer by @Gregory Kuhn.

with open(Path(__file__).parent / Path('_static/css/user.define.rst'), 'r') as f:
    user_define_role = f.read()

rst_prolog = '\n'.join([ user_define_role + '\n',])  # will be included at the beginning of every source file that is read.
# rst_epilog = '\n'.join([ user_define_role + '\n',])  # it's ok if you put it on the end.
```

user.define.rst

```
.. role:: strike
```

user.define.css

```css
.strike {text-decoration: line-through;}
```

With the `rst_prolog`, It can auto-add the role on each rst files, but if you change the content( that file, it contains a format that you define), then you must [rebuild](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.2/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-E) to make the render is correct.

## 3.Create roles

You can create an extension to achieve it.

```py
# conf.py

extensions = ['_ext.rst_roles', ]
html_static_path = ['_static', ]
html_css_files = ['css/user.define.css']
```

```py
# rst_roles.py
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from docutils.parsers.rst import roles
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst.states import Inliner


def strike_role(role, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner: Inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    your_css_strike_name = 'strike'
    return nodes.inline(rawtext, text, **dict(classes=[your_css_strike_name])), []

def setup(app: Sphinx):
    roles.register_canonical_role('my-strike', strike_role)  # usage:  :my-strike:`content ...`
```

The full architecture:

- conf.py
- _ext/

  - rst_roles.py
- _static/

  - css/

    - user.define.css

about the rules, you can reference this link [rst-roles](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/howto/rst-roles.html)

And I vary recommended you to see the `docutils.parsers.rst.roles.py` .

Comment: I don't know why my answer makes someone unhappy then give me a vote down and I hope you can tell me why,
anyway, I update my solution hope you will understand.

Comment: **This is the optimum answer,** currently. The first "Only one file." solution is *really* optimal. It's the only solution that actually works for the common case of a reST file hosted on a third-party site *not* under your direct control (e.g., GitHub- or GitLab-hosted `README.rst`). Haters gonna hate, @Carson. I wouldn't take the downvotes personally. They just jelly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Python definition of a `del` role, which works better than the accepted answer if you want to use the role in multiple pages of a Pelican blog or a Sphinx documentation project:

```py
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import roles

def deleted_role(_role, rawtext, text, _lineno, _inliner, options={}, _content=[]):
    roles.set_classes(options)
    options.setdefault('classes', []).append("del")
    return [nodes.inline(rawtext, text, **options)], []

roles.register_canonical_role('del', deleted_role)
```

Even better would be to extend the HTML writer to produce a proper `<del>` tag, like this:

```py
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import roles
from docutils.writers._html_base import HTMLTranslator

class delnode(nodes.inline):
    pass

def visit_delnode(self, node):
    self.body.append(self.starttag(node, 'del', ''))
def depart_delnode(self, node):
    self.body.append('</del>')

HTMLTranslator.visit_delnode = visit_delnode
HTMLTranslator.depart_delnode = depart_delnode

def deleted_role(_role, rawtext, text, _lineno, _inliner, options={}, _content=[]):
    roles.set_classes(options)
    return [delnode(rawtext, text, **options)], []

roles.register_canonical_role('del', deleted_role)
```

You can trivially adjust it to produce an `<s>`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an extension for this.
Just `pip install sphinxnotes-strike` and use:

```
:strike:`text`
```

or

```
:del:`text`
```

to show strike text.

For more info: https://sphinx-notes.github.io/strike/

Answer (score 1):

Since Docutils 0.17, the HTML5-writer uses `<del>` if a matching class value is found in `inline`, `literal`, or `container` elements:

```
.. role:: del

:del:`This text has been deleted`, here is the rest of the paragraph.

.. container:: del

  This paragraph has been deleted.
```

Spinx users may consider to add the role definition to their [rst_prolog](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog).