# How do I create a global role/roles in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

This is a followup of "ReST Strikethrough" [ReST strikethrough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6518788/1268478) but in a Sphinx rather than ReST context.  My question is whether there is a central place in sphinx where to put a "role" directive or whether this directive really has to be repeated in every rst file within a sphinx docmentation.

In more detail:

It is easy to define custom CSS styles for inline text (see ReST Strikethrough as example) using a role directive:

```
.. role:: custom
   :class: custom

This is an :custom:`inline text`.
```

which translates into a html rendering of

```
.. This is an <span class="custom">inline text</span>.  ..
```

Also, a custom stylesheet can easily be added to sphinx (see http://www.tinkerer.me/doc/theming.html) where to add a CSS class selector to control how "custom" text is rendered (color, strikethrough, font, size...)

What disturbes me is that in my experiments, I had to repeat the role directive in every ReST file that used the custom role.  Is there a "central" place where I can define this once for the whole site?

Comment: Updated Tinkerer link: http://www.tinkerer.me/doc/more_tinkering.html#theming

Comment: I added some explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24932178/2923406

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems that [rst_prolog](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst-prolog) that is set in the conf.py file is the central place that I was looking for.  Rst_prolog is "A string of reStructuredText that will be included at the beginning of every source file that is read".  In my case, I simply added the following to conf.py:

```
rst_prolog = """
.. role:: test2
"""
```

Note also that for my purpose, the *role* directive without a class attibute works just fine.

Obviously, as Chris has pointed out, an rst_prolog that accomplishes many things could be achieved by including a *global.rst* file.  [There may be issues with its relative path, however.  Maybe better to use rst_prolog = open('global.rst', 'r').read() --untested]

Comment: This is brilliant. I not only added `rst_prolog = open('global.rst', 'r').read()` to "conf.py", but I added "global.rst" to `exclude_patterns`:

    exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store', '.git', 'global.rst']

to keep it from being processed - otherwise Sphinx generates warnings about duplicate definitions.

Answer (score 7):

From the example at [documenting your project using sphinx](http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html), you can use [`include`](http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#includes) to substitute a `global.rst` file, which contains all your role directives, into your other files. From this site:

> The syntax:
>
> ```
> .. include:: myfile.rst
> ```
>
> Will "inline" the given file (`myfile.rst`).
>   A common convention I use is create a global .rst file called `global.rst` and include that at the top of every page. Very useful for links to common images or common files links, etc.

Comment: I believe it's `.. include:: myfile.rst`