# Inline code highlighting in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

I know reStructuredText has this directive:

```
.. code:: bash

    gedit pohl.m
```

which renders a code block. Is there some way to get syntax highlighting for inline snippets like this:

```
Do edit the file, type ``gedit pohl.m`` into a terminal.
```

The backticks mark it as code, but I'd like to highlight it with pygments like the block. Is this possible?

Comment: The backticks mark that part of the text as an [inline literal](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#inline-markup), not as a code block. Typically this will just be published in a monospace font. I'm not sure how to get inline code syntax highlighted snippets I'm afraid.

Comment: See [Inline code highlighting § Roles — Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#inline-code-highlighting).

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Having looked into this some more I stumbled upon the document [reStructuredText Interpreted Text Roles](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html). From this document:

> Interpreted text uses backquotes (`) around the text. An explicit role marker may optionally appear before or after the text, delimited with colons. For example:
>
> ```
> This is `interpreted text` using the default role.
>
> This is :title:`interpreted text` using an explicit role.
> ```

It seems that there is a [`code` role](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#code), so you can simply type

```
:code:`a = b + c`
```

to render an inline code block. To get syntax highlighting you can define a custom role. For example

```
.. role:: bash(code)
   :language: bash
```

which you can then use like so:

```
Here is some awesome bash code :bash:`a = b + c`.
```

Note that the role definition must be placed before references to the role.

Note, the document I link to makes no mention of the version of docutils to which it refers. The code role is *not* available in docutils 0.8.1 (which is the only version I have to test against).

Comment: please note this issue when using sphinx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591107/sphinx-inline-code-highlight

Comment: The code role was added in Docutils 0.9 (2012-05-02).

Comment: The role definition may be placed before or after the role. https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#interpreted-text

Answer (score 4):

For me I had to create a [`docutils.conf`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/config.html#syntax-highlight) file in the Sphinx's [configuration directory](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/glossary.html#term-configuration-directory) (where `conf.py` resides).
It had the following contents:

```
[restructuredtext parser]
syntax_highlight = short
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655335/11392196) answer for more information on the above

To set the role globally, in the `conf.py` file, I created a [`rst_prolog`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog) variable. The string inside it will be included at the beginning of every source file that is read.

```py
rst_prolog = """
.. role:: python(code)
    :language: python
    :class: highlight
"""
```

In this `highlight` class was necessary for proper Python highlighting.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707879/11392196) answer for more information on the above