# What is the equivalent of ` tag in restructured text?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, restructuredtext

In markdown there is a very useful "tag" for inline code with "`".

So it is easy to higlight `some_code()` directly in a sentence.

I would like to know if there is an equivalent in Restructured text?

I know that I can use `.. code-block:: a_language` for large blocks with syntaxe highlighting but it is not what I'm looking for.

For the moment I use `**word**` instead but I would prefer not to use it for this purpose.

Thanks,

Damien

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870719/inline-code-highlighting-in-rest/12365251#12365251).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I marked the question as duplicate too.