# Inline code highlighting in Sphinx (reST)

Tags: html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to get inline code snippets highlighted while using Sphinx.

I've looked at solution provided at [Inline code highlighting in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870719/inline-code-highlighting-in-restructuredtext?rq=1) but it does not work for me. I'm using Sphinx 1.4.8.

Is there another simple and elegant way of marking inline code to be highlighted?

In absence of a full solution, i.e. one that supports true language-based highlighting, I would be happy having ability to set a non-black colour for my inline code throughout the document. Is that possible?

Edit1:
Here's my code:

```
.. role:: py(code)
   :language: python

here is some inline code :py:`def func():`
```

The text row here gets rendered all in black instead of keyword 'def' in 
another colour. Highlighting works perfectly for code-blocks but not inline.

Edit2:

Humbalan's suggestion helped me almost solve this.
I added following to `$SPHINX_PROJECT_DIR/_templates/layout.html`:

```
{# layout.html #}
{# Import the theme's layout. #}
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% set css_files = css_files + ['_static/style.css'] %}
```

Then i created `$SPHINX_PROJECT_DIR/_templates/style.css` with following contents to override `span.pre`:

```
span.pre{
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #feeaea
}
```

I'm closer to the solution but not quite there yet. I get following output now:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what means "it does not work" and post your code.

Comment: Your "Edit2" again tells us what you *don't* want. but please describe which result you would like to have. From my point of view you've got what you have programmed: red text, black border with 2px distance to the text and a backgroud of the defined colour.

Comment: The solution provided at [Inline code highlighting in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870719/inline-code-highlighting-in-restructuredtext?rq=1) should work with Docutils >= 0.9 (2012-05-02) if you also include a "docutils.conf" file as described in answer 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I highlight code snippets in my doc:

```
.. sourcecode:: python

    a code line 
    another code line
```

Does that help you?

---

**Edit:**

I did some research as I am interested in an answer too. For me it seems that the grey code is default in some (or all?) themes, I tested *sphinxdoc* and *bizstyle*. If you check the html code of the snippet (e. g. with Firefox's debugger) you get this if you use *sphinxdoc*

```
<p>here is some inline code 
<code class="code py python docutils literal">
<span class="keyword">
    <span class="pre">def</span>
</span> 
<span class="name function">
    <span class="pre">func</span>
</span>
<span class="punctuation">
    <span class="pre">():</span>
</span>
</code>
</p>
```

Here you can see that you could define a style for "def", another one for "func" and a 3rd one for "():" in a layout.css of your sphinx project. Example:

```
code.py.python.docutils.literal  { background-color: Bisque; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid maroon; }
code.py.python.docutils.literal span.keyword { background-color: red; color:white; }
code.py.python.docutils.literal span.name.function { background-color: pink; color:green; }
code.py.python.docutils.literal span.punctuation { background-color: yellow; color:brown; }
```

Result:

[image: syntax highlight with role]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately not. As I said, highlighting works as intended in code-blocks but I'd like to get coloured text in inline code that is usually marked with two leading and two trailing backticks.

Comment: OK, I see. If you highlight with :py:`myfunc` the highlighting works only if there is really a documented method (or function) with the name "myfunc". And if this method is in another module you must provide the path like :py:meth:`module.class.myfunc`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to show the charakter which includes "myfunc". So I you see text with a  grey backgrounc it is the syntax like in your exampel above ":py:..."