# Make a CSS button a link in Sphinx

Tags: css, jinja2, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have added a css button from http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ to Sphinx using the suggestions from [How do I create a global role/roles in Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9698702/161801). I have

```
.. role:: button
   :class: button
```

And I can get it with

```
:button:`button text`
```

I now want this button to be a link to cross reference to a different page, basically, be the "text" for

```
:ref:`text <Reference>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/conda/conda-docs/blob/master/web/button.py) is a simple Sphinx extension to do the trick.  Take the CSS for the button you want and add it as `source/_static/button.css` (call the tag `button`).

Then add button.py alongside `source`, and add

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

to your `conf.py` (if it isn't there already) so that it can find it, and add `'button'` to the extensions list in `conf.py`.

Then use it like

```
.. button::
   :text: Button Text
   :link: link/to/stuff.html
```

Thanks a ton to [Bryan Van de Ven](https://github.com/bryevdv) for writing most of this extension.

Comment: Your link to the button.py Sphinx extension no longer works as that particular repository went through refactoring and it was removed. The latest version of button.py that existed there can be found here: https://github.com/conda/conda-docs/blob/04613488d57688d77b0bc20618b9a4d5b56947ed/web/button.py

Answer (score 1):

This [script](https://github.com/conda/conda-docs/blob/04613488d57688d77b0bc20618b9a4d5b56947ed/web/button.py) is great !!!!!!

but I want to use the [role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html), so I do some modify:

```
...

def button_role(role, rawtext, text, line_no, in_liner: Inliner, options: Dict = None, content: List = None):
    text, link = text.split('|')
    node = ButtonNode()
    node['text'] = text.rstrip()
    node['link'] = link.rstrip()
    return [node], []


def setup(app: Sphinx):

    ...

    """
    :btn:`text | link`
    """
    roles.register_canonical_role('btn', button_role)
```

usage:

```
Hello :btn:`Click me to SO | https://stackoverflow.com/` !!!
```

## Full code (v2)

**version 2**:

- add style
- and now you don't need to add `:text:` on the `directives` (use `has_content` instead of it.)

```
from docutils import nodes
import jinja2
from docutils.parsers.rst.directives import unchanged
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from docutils.parsers.rst import roles
from docutils.parsers.rst.states import Inliner
from typing import List, Dict
import re

BUTTON_TEMPLATE = jinja2.Template("""
{% if link  %} 
    <a href="{{ link }}">    
        <button class="{{ class }}" {{ style |default('') }}>{{ text }}</button>
    </a>
{% else %}
    <button class="{{ class }}" {{ style |default('') }}>{{ text }}</button>
{% endif %}
""")


# placeholder node for document graph
class ButtonNode(nodes.Element):
    ...


class ButtonDirective(Directive):
    has_content = True
    required_arguments = 0

    """
    You have to set `option_spec` before you do the following
    .. xxx::
        :link:
        :class:
    """
    option_spec = {
        'link': unchanged,
        'class': unchanged,
        'style': unchanged,
    }

    # this will execute when your directive is encountered
    # it will insert a ButtonNode into the document that will
    # get visisted during the build phase
    def run(self):
        # env = self.state.document.settings.env
        # app: Sphinx = env.app
        # app.add_css_file('css/button/solid-blue-btn.css')  # or you can set it on the conf.py

        node = ButtonNode()
        node['text'] = ''.join(self.content.data)
        """
        .. button::
            :class: solid-blue-btn

            content.data[0]
            content.data[1]

        .. button:: content.data[0]
            :class: solid-blue-btn                
        """
        # style = "background-color:green; font-size: 30px;"

        node['class'] = self.options['class'].strip()
        node['link'] = self.options.get('link')
        if self.options.get('style'):
            style = 'style=' + self.options['style']  # style = "background-color:green; font-size: 30px;"
            node['style'] = style
        return [node]


# build phase visitor emits HTML to append to output
def html_visit_button_node(self, node: ButtonNode):
    # html = BUTTON_TEMPLATE.render(text=node['text'], link=node['link'])
    html = BUTTON_TEMPLATE.render({k: v for k, v in node.attributes.items()})
    self.body.append(''.join([_.strip() for _ in html.split('\n') if _.strip()]))
    raise nodes.SkipNode


def button_role(role, rawtext, text, line_no, in_liner: Inliner, options: Dict = None, content: List = None):
    # 'link="https://www.google.com/" style="background-color:green; font-size: 30px;"'
    regex = re.compile(f"(?:.*"
                       fr"(?P<link>link=\S*)|"
                       fr"(?P<style>style=\S*)"
                       f")",
                       )

    text, cls, *options = text.split('|')
    node = ButtonNode()  # nodes.paragraph
    node['class'] = cls.strip()
    node['text'] = text.rstrip()

    if options:
        options: str = options[0].strip()
        for attr in options.split(' '):
            m = regex.match(attr)
            if m:
                dict_option = m.groupdict()
                if dict_option.get('link'):
                    dict_option['link'] = dict_option['link'][5:]  # remove link=
                for key, value in dict_option.items():
                    if value:
                        node[key] = value.strip()
    return [node], []


def setup(app: Sphinx):

    """
    .. button::
        option1:
        option2:
    """
    app.add_node(ButtonNode,
                 # ↓ kwargs
                 html=(html_visit_button_node, lambda: None)
                 # other_2: Tuple[Callable, Callable],
                 # other_3: Tuple[visit_xxx, depart_xxx],
                 )
    app.add_directive('button', ButtonDirective)

    """
    :btn:``
    """
    roles.register_canonical_role('btn', button_role)
```

## Test

```
.. button:: Google
    :class: btn-solid-blue
    :style: "background-color:green; font-size:30px;"
    :link: https://www.google.com/

.. button:: FB (no link)
    :class: btn-solid-blue


- .. button:: Google
    :class: btn-solid-blue
    :link: https://www.google.com/

- .. button:: FB (no link)
    :class: btn-solid-blue

----

Hello :btn:`link | btn-solid-blue | link=https://stackoverflow.com/` !!!

Hello :btn:`bg f-size | btn-solid-blue | style="font-size:30px;"` !!!

Hello :btn:`bg font-size | btn-hollow-red | style="background-color:yellow; font-size:30px;"` !!!

Hello :btn:`font-size | btn-hollow-red | style="font-size:50px;"` !!!

Hello :btn:`link | btn-hollow-red | link=https://stackoverflow.com/` !!!

Hello\ :btn:`none | btn-hollow-black`\!!!
```

**where class `btn-hollow` was modified from https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_hover**

[image]

## Reference

- [native-directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class)

  You can go to `docutils.parsers.rst.directives` ::

  ```
  admonitions.py
  body.py
  html.py
  images.py
  misc.py
  parts.py
  references.py
  tables.py
  ```

  ↑ Choose one that you are interested in and to see how to implement a directive class.
- [roles](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#id7)

  - to see the detail: `docutils.parsers.rst.roles.py`
- [rst-directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/howto/rst-directives.html)
- sphinx.application.[add_node](https://sphinx-rtd-trial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_node)
- [Jinja: List of Builtin Filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters)
- [Jinja: Filters: default](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="https://any.website.notExistWebsite.weirdExtension"><button>Text here...</button></a>
```

Use this