# ReStructuredText bold text with subscript

Tags: python-sphinx, pandoc, restructuredtext

Is it possible to have subscript inside of bold text in restructured text?

i.e.

```
**H :sub:`2` O**
```

Will render as   `` `H :sub:`2` O `` in bold instead of `H2O` (with subscript 2)

I'm guessing from this thread it isn't:
[Bold italic in ReStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984652/bold-italic-in-restructuredtext)

I'm converting html files into rst and stripping all the subscript elements out of bold text is inconvenient!

Comment: You cannot have nested formatting in reST. See https://docutils.sourceforge.io/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is it's not possible with reStructuredText. You cannot have inline element inside another inline element, i.e. you can't have bold sentence with bold and emphasised word inside it. Or, your case - subscript within bold text. [details](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible)

However, if you target to HTML, there is workaround based on [raw role](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw).

```
.. role:: raw-html(raw)
   :format: html

Water formula is :raw-html:`<strong>H<sub>2</sub>O</strong>`.
```

Another alternative is use [math](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/es/1.7/ext/math.html) role and type chemical formulas as math formula. If your case, water written using amslatex syntax is

```
:math:`H_2O`.
```