# Customize sphinxdoc theme

Tags: python, themes, python-sphinx

Is there an easy way to customize the existing `sphinxdoc` theme? For the default theme, there are many theme-attributes, but in sphinxdoc I can't even set a logo or change some colors.

Or can you recommend me a site where I can learn how to modify themes?

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html#overriding-or-replacing-a-theme-s-stylesheet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All I wanted is to add [ReST strikethrough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6518788/2923406) in my sphinx doc. Here is how I did it:

```
$ cd my-sphinx-dir
$ mkdir -p theme/static
$ touch theme/theme.conf
$ touch theme/static/style.css
```

In `theme/theme.conf`:

```
[theme]
inherit = default
stylesheet = style.css
pygments_style = pygments.css
```

(this makes it look like the default theme (l. 2))

In `theme/static/style.css`:

```
@import url("default.css"); /* make sure to sync this with the base theme's css filename */

.strike {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Then, in your conf.py:

```
html_theme = 'theme' # use the theme in subdir 'theme'
html_theme_path = ['.'] # make sphinx search for themes in current dir
```

More here: https://sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/master/theming.html.

(Optional) In global.rst:

```
.. role:: strike
   :class: strike
```

and in a example.rst:

```
.. include:: global.rst

:strike:`This looks like it is outdated.`
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to customize the existing `sphinxdoc` theme, you need to create a custom **template** and **stylesheet** that contains the desired modifications.

---

### `_templates` and `_static` subfolders

In your sphinx documentation folder (named `docs` in this example), create two subfolders: `_static` and `_templates`:

```
docs
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
└── _templates
    └── page.html
└── _static
    └── style.css
```

---

### `style.css` stylesheet

In the `_static` folder, create a file `style.css` containing CSS options that you wish to overwrite. You can find the applicable options by looking at the `sphinxdoc` theme stylesheet, inside the sphinx installation folder:

```
./python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.4.egg/sphinx/themes/sphinxdoc/static/sphinxdoc.css_t`
```

To change the document background from white to black, add the following lines to `style.css`:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
div.document {
    background-color: black;
}
```

To add the ability to center your code using the `.. rst-class:: centered` directive, add the following lines:

```
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

etc...

---

### `page.html` template

In the `_templates` subfolder, create a file `page.html` with the following content:

```
{% extends "!page.html" %}

{% set css_files = css_files + ["_static/style.css"] %}
```

This tells sphinx to look for the `style.css` stylesheet in the `_static` folder.

---

## More information

These instructions are from the Tinkerer documentation on theming: http://tinkerer.me/doc/theming.html. Tinkerer is a blogging engine based on Sphinx.

Also, see: [How to add custom css file to Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462494/how-to-add-custom-css-file).

Answer (score 4):

Unless I misunderstand you, the [standard Sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html) tells you how to modify existing and create new themes.

I actually installed the Sphinx [cloud theme](http://packages.python.org/cloud_sptheme/cloud_theme.html), and then started editing its templates; so I had a new theme where I could see exactly what is required, but that I didn't need to create from scratch.

If you want to alter the CSS layout, you can add CSS files (or images) into the `_static` subdirectory of your `source`, and edit your `conf.py` as necessary. Again, the cloud theme was my best example for that.

Answer (score 1):

For Sphinx 1.8.2 the default theme is [Alabaster](https://github.com/bitprophet/alabaster) which I customize by adding a new stylesheet configured with [html_style](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_style):

`conf.py`:

```
html_style = 'custom.css'
```

`_static/custom.css`:

```
@import url("alabaster.css");

blockquote{
  background: white;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think the file also can be named _static/custom.css_t