# How can I change text justification to 'justify' for the ReadTheDocs Sphinx theme?

Tags: css, themes, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm writing a new documentation for my project in reST. The documentation is rendered with Sphinx on ReadTheDocs. I already downloaded the ReadTheDocs theme as a git submodule into my repositories `docs/source/_themes` folder, so I can modify some of the templates or CSS settings.

I would like to change the text justification for big paragraphs from *ragged right* to *fully justified*.
Where can I change his in the hundreds of lines of CSS code?

**Document structure:**

```
...
<div class="section" id="basic-2-flip-flop-synchronizer">
  <h2>Basic 2 Flip-Flop Synchronizer</h2>
  <p>The 2 flip-flop ....

  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS code to include or replace with:**

```
text-align:justify;
```

*I used CSS 10 years ago, but I'm not really up-to-date on the new CSS selectors ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the document structure has seen an update between 2016 and 2023, and sphinx now uses `<section>` tags rather than `<div class="section">`. If you want to align all sections, just lose the dot in `_static/css/custom.css`:

```
section {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

And to register this custom css (according to [docs.readthedocs.io](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html)):

```
## conf.py

# These folders are copied to the documentation's HTML output
html_static_path = ['_static']

# These paths are either relative to html_static_path
# or fully qualified paths (eg. https://...)
html_css_files = [
    'css/custom.css',
]
```

Comment: The biggest problem of RTD theme is its incompatibility with docutils since months (or even years). RTD theme works only with old Sphinx 5.3, no Sphinx 6.x and no Sphinx 7.x ...

Answer (score 2):

You can directly modify the `css` file inside `docs/source/_themes` by adding the following block

```
.section #basic-2-flip-flop-synchronizer{
     text-align:justify;
}
```

I would suggest to put this code block at the very end of `css` file because it will override the css property if `.section #basic-2-flip-flop-synchronizer` happen to appear somewhere inside css file.

Like @Ricardo Ruiz Melendez suggested below, the best practice to change a `css` file is to use your customized `css` file. You can find a step-by-step guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622698/customize-sphinxdoc-theme) and some on [official website](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html)

Comment: I recommend adding this line of code in your custom css if you have one, which should be linked after your theme css. It's better to override the theme's classes this way just in case you need to update the template to a newer version in the future, without the need of identifying which classes you changed inside that file.