# Customizing an imported theme in Sphinx

Tags: python, themes, python-sphinx

I really like the [sphinx-better-theme](https://sphinx-better-theme.readthedocs.io), but it doesn't have a responsive collapsible menu like I want. I am trying to add this following the answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622698/customize-sphinxdoc-theme), but When I run `make html` I get

```
Theme error:
no theme named 'better' found, inherited by 'theme'
```

My theme/theme.conf file has:

```
[theme]
inherit = better
stylesheet = style.css
pygments_style= pygments.css
```

I've done some customization adding my own css file, but to get the responsive menu I need to add to the templates themselves. Is this possible to customize this way without editing the theme's built-in templates?

**Update on 5/24/2017**

I think I have narrowed it down to the css files. The better theme uses css_t files, so the actual `better.css` file is generated from this template when I use the better theme out of the box. So what I need to do is find a way to get the better.css_t file to be processed and included in the final output.

My `conf.py` file contains:

```
html_theme = 'theme'
html_theme_options = {'cssfiles': ['_static/butterick.css']}
```

My `theme/static/style.css` file:

```
import url("better.css");
import url("butterick.css");
```

So how do I get the template engine to process that template?

Comment: Did you follow the theme's [installation instructions](https://sphinx-better-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)? Did you build the docs before trying to modify the theme?

Comment: Yes to both. The theme is installed and running correctly when I use it out of the box. I was hoping to find a solution similar to the one in the referenced question. I have imported the theme into my conf.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
[theme]
inherit = basic
```

Most of the themes extend from the basic theme and I guess this can solve you problem.