# Sphinx adding background image

Tags: python, django, background-image, jinja2, python-sphinx

I'm new to Sphinx docs generator and I want to add a background image to the website. How can I handle that ? I tried to put the bg image to the static folder and tried adding it to the css but it still doesn't appear.

Comment: How are you adding the image? Does it appear in your build folder? Are you sure that path in CSS is correct?

Comment: @errata Hi, I could manage adding it in CSS, but I want to actually add it as a static image. I'm using JinJa2 templating engine and I'm not sure if adding the static images directly to CSS is a correct way. I try to find a way to add it as a static img.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622698/customize-sphinxdoc-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add image you can use [`image` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image), for example:

```
.. image:: _static/path/to/your/image.png
   :scale: 10 %
   :align: left
   :class: intro-logo
```

Since you can add `class` to it, you can modify your style directly in CSS.

Also, be sure that you defined your static folder in `conf.py`:

```
html_static_path = ['_static']
```