# How to do strikethrough in a reStructuredText file hosted on GitHub?

Tags: github, restructuredtext, strikethrough

I am converting a *README.md* file to *README.rst*. The reason is, I am going to make a package available to PyPi. I am forced to use **.rst**.

My conversion is nearly complete, but I have a strikethrough line in my markdown file, e.g.:

```
~~This text is crossed out~~
```

which renders on GitHub as crossed out. But I am unable to do this in reStructuredText. A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6652379/939986) on StackOverflow suggests defining a **strike** like this:

```
.. role:: strike
    :class: strike
```

And using something like this in the CSS file:

```
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

And do strikethrough like this:

```
:strike:`This text is crossed out`
```

But the problem is I have no control over CSS file of GitHub.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also use substitutions to make multiple uses easier. Put this markup somewhere in your file:

```
.. |ss| raw:: html

   <strike>

.. |se| raw:: html

   </strike>
```

Then just enclose the text to be struck out with `|ss|` & `|se|`:

```
One, |ss| two |se|, three |ss| strikes |se| you're out!
```

will render as:

One,  <s>two</s> , three  <s>strikes</s>  you're out!

Just be sure to have space around the substitution elements, so they are parsed correctly. It looks a bit awkward here, but this is a contrived example.

Answer (score 5):

Not so clean solution, but works for me.

```
.. raw:: html

   <s>

This text is crossed out

.. raw:: html

   </s>
```

Comment: Using [Nikola static blogger](https://getnikola.com/) I had to use replace your `<s>` with `<s>This text is crossed out.</s>` and leave out the last `.. raw:: html` directive. Then strikethrough text was rendered in the Nikola output. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible right now as the Markdown equivalent is top level [GitHub Flavored Markdown syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown), whereas with the RST it is a [document-specific style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629060/56039). On GitHub's repository rendering, there are currently no CSS additions permitted.

Comment: As [Praveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916125/praveen-kumar)'s [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29065401/2809027) suggests, this _is_ actually feasible... for the specific (_albeit common_) output format of HTML. Although the reST standard provides no explicit support for strikethrough, it _does_ provide explicit support for  embedding raw HTML tags – including the `<s>...</s>` strikethrough tag. Naturally, this falls down for non-HTML output (e.g., PDF). When life hands you lemons, you hack HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use https://www.thefancytext.com/strikethrough-text-generator.

S̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶o̶u̶t̶

Ain't fancy, but if you copy and paste it in your editor, pandoc should take it.